# how can i call a php function inside a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, input

I have a form like this:

```html
<div class="modal-body" method="POST">
    <input type="text" hidden="" id="idpersonM" name="" disabled=»disabled required>
    <label>Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="apellidoM" class="form-control input-sm" required>
    <label>Cuit</label>
    <input type="text" name="cuitM" id="cuitM" class="form-control input-sm" required>
    <?php 
        mostrar_pdf("./pdf/".$_POST['#cuitM']."/");
    ?>
</div>
```

My idea is to call `mostrar_pdf($dirname)` using the input var `cuitM`. The problem is: i can't read `cuitM` because i am not sending the form.

`mostrar_pdf($dirname)` takes a dirname and shows all the files in it.
So the `$dirname` should be like:

```
$direname = "./pdf/"(cuitM input)"/"
```

Is this a possible approach to the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Side note: This character > `»disabled` - you need to remove it.

Comment: Second side note: `<div>` does not have `method` property. Probably you need to look into `<form>` element

Answer (score 0):

I find a diferenct solution not so related to this problem.

I create a div in my form like this:

`<div id="cont1"></div>`

So i can fill it from a js function.

```
var a = '<a target="_blank" href="pdf/' + data +'/' + data2 +'">Escribiir</a>';
document.getElementById('cont1').innerHTML= a;
```

where 'data' and 'data2' come from a database.

Answer (score -1):

You can't execute php script on the client's side.

If you don't want the page to reload a solution would be to use an ajax call to send the input's content and then receive the function's data.

Here are some documentation about XML http request,jquery ajax and fetch api:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API